# netstat -lnp outputing results without PID

Tags: networking, netstat

After using `netstat -lnp` I wonder how comes some of the result don't show any PID/Program name? Should I be worried? See below:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33223         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31952/dart          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5037          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13351/adb           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41741         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5433          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5434          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:33223               :::*                    LISTEN      31952/dart          
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:63342         :::*                    LISTEN      1061/java           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8599          :::*                    LISTEN      1061/java           
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:6942          :::*                    LISTEN      1061/java           
udp        0      0 224.0.0.251:5353        0.0.0.0:*                           26664/chrome        
udp        0      0 224.0.0.251:5353        0.0.0.0:*                           26664/chrome        
udp        0      0 224.0.0.251:5353        0.0.0.0:*                           26705/chrome --type 
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
raw6       0      0 :::58                   :::*                    7           -
```

---

I have identified some of them:

- Port _621: Printing
- Port 5939: Teamviewer
- Port 5433 and 5434: PostgresQL

Comment: Did you call `netstat -lnp` with root rights (for instance using `sudo`)?

Comment: no, thank you I just did and got information about each one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In netstat, you won't see PIDs if it is a kernel process. Also, like @Mathias Weidner was suggesting, you won't see the PID if the user invoking netstat isn't  privileged enough.